# OkHttpClient with Mobile Carrier issue

Tags: android, tcp, socket.io, httpurlconnection, okhttp

My Application API perform weird behavior. One of my live app's api expected response time 2 to 3 seconds but it takes long time to response!

Test Cases:

1. Works with WIFI = **Yes**
2. Works with Airtel carrier = **Yes**
3. Works with Jio carrier = **Yes**
4. Works in Other countries network =**Yes**
5. Works in mobile browser with Vodafone Idea carrier = **Yes**
6. Works with Same API with IOS app using Vodafone Idea carrier = **Yes**

#### Main Issue: Issue with **Vodafone Idea carrier** using App = Very Slow

**Case1.**

```
 URL url = new URL("https://example.com");
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (code !=  200) {
                    throw new IOException("Invalid response from server: " + code);
                }

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("data", line);
                }
```

**Outcome:**

- First time 40 to 50 seconds.
- On every next consecutive call it will return within 2 to 5 seconds as per expectation.

**Case 2:**

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

        Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://example.com")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        Log.e("APi", "REQUEST: "+request.toString());

        Call call1 = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                Log.e("APi", "APi Failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.e("APi", "APi isSuccessful:" + response.isSuccessful());
                Log.e("APi", "Response:" + response.body().string());
            }
        });
```

**Outcome:**

- Every time takes 40 to 50 seconds.

**Case 3:**

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://example.com")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            Log.e("APi", "REQUEST: "+request.toString());
    
            Call call1 = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
            call1.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                    Log.e("APi", "APi Failed");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                    Log.e("APi", "APi isSuccessful:" + response.isSuccessful());
                    Log.e("APi", "Response:" + response.body().string());
                }
            });
```

**Outcome:**

- Every time it takes 5 to 6 seconds.

Note: I am afraid to use .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) as 1 second in app It started to give more api failure and not looks correct solution as well.

#### Update CaseStudy:

https://github.com/square/okhttp
Detail debug of OkHttpClient.
it gives below error 4 times approx.

```
failed to connect to xxx.com/2001:4860:4802:36::15 (port XXX) from /2402:3a80:1b8f:ca21:847:21a8:5ffc:fc30 (port XXX) after 10000ms
```

package okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection class.
trying to establish **connectSocket** but getting error.

**-> After adding "www" [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) into my domain.
Response time change from 40 seconds to 12 seconds approx for okhttp library.**

Comment: You should collect some events using a listener and add them to your question https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/

Comment: @YuriSchimke Thanks. Added exception at debug time. Please note issue come on only 1 specific network only!

Comment: In My App also, we have Google Cloud Engine for server and Using firebase storage and cloud functionalities @YuriSchimke

Comment: Interesting issue, but I fear that we are missing the full picture. 

Could it be that you are making a really lot of other connections in your app? 

I don't think this code you give would be able to reproduce the issue you are describing by itself, so creating a minimal reproducible example would help a lot.

Comment: Your message shows an IPv6 address. Do the scenarios that work faster use IPv4 or IPv6?

Comment: @francisduvivier its plain project with single API. created for testing only. By applying www before domain again response time change from 40 second to 11 to 13 seconds

Comment: Could you upload that project somewhere public and provide a link?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to see the whole picture because you don't explain how you execute the subsequent connections. It is entirely possible that you are reusing an existing connection. By default, HTTP/1.1 keeps connections alive.

Checking to see if using **plain-text HTTP vs. HTTPS makes a difference** could be interesting, too, as the connection setup cost is higher with HTTPS. Your client may also do more verification based on the certificate that is returned.

If changing the hostname makes so much difference, then I would definitely look at **how the name resolver is configured** on the system.

I would also **capture network traffic** and see what is taking long. tcpdump is your
friend or you could always consider using [wireshark](https://wireshark.org)

As others have suggested, you may also want to **disable the IPv6 stack** on the box to rule out as the source of the problem.

Comment: i have checked with my teammates  who has good knowledge at networking level, we found that even "traceroute <<Domain>>" in terminal takes too much time! On conclusion. i have used "HttpsURLConnection" and on very first time keep setConnectTimeout for 1 seconds. for any other next calls it will regular time out!

Comment: traceroute can be misleading especially if you are using a hostname vs. an IP address. Some network equipment may also block some traffic. Your best bet is a network traffic analyzer.